# Jira cleaning responsibility

Tags: jira, agile, jira-agile

We have a team of 20 people divided in 2 teams and a jira bord for both of them. We work on agile scrum methodology.

The team components are a pm/scrum master, BA, PO, testing team, ux,ui and backend dev team. The problem we have is that the bord gets messy and no one is taking care of it.

My question is who should take care of the bord to not get a mess pm, scrum master dev team?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because project-management is off-topic on SO.

Comment: @BDL good to know this. Thank you I've voted personally to close this questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally it is the Scrum teams responsibility (everybody). The beauty of Agile lies in self driven and empowered teams. Don't try to command and control and make it habit of everyone. "Scrum master/PO" can facilitate this (help other team members to close task/US after discussion of their state see point no 2 below). If you try to hold one person responsible for it you will loose granular info and your Agile/Jira board will not reflect actual info.

> "The problem we have is that the board gets messy and no one is taking
>   care of it."

If your team follow agile properly this situation will not occur.

1. Every team member update their respective task and US regularly(daily).
2. Use Agile ceremonies Grooming/Planning/Demo(acceptance of US) for Clean up task. Discuss with team [merge duplicates/Priorities and delete obsolete one.
3. one of the Agile principle is Limit work in progress:One should not keep more than 1 US/task in in-progress. Should complete one and and move on. Or else if he is blocked then only pick next one.
   4.At end of sprint/Iteration Conclude US's state Accepted/Completed/Carryover/removed/Moved to backlog.
4. We usually take it(Clean up) as a retrospective action item and make sure stewardship followed in next sprint not only with respect to code but JIRA as well.

> "Re-iterating: you can request PO or scrum master to facilitate/watch
>   it. but better to ask your team member to take this responsibility. or
>   Story owner should make sure his/her user story [JIRA in your case]
>   reach to a conclusive state and cleaned up in JIRA."

Answer (score 3):

We update & clean the board at the Daily Scrum. This makes sense as everyone is telling what they completed yesterday. After the Scrum board is updated we start planning the day.

In this case the Scrum Master should teach the Scrum team to self-organize and keep the Scrum board up-to-date.